# How can I insert an array into one row?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert

The following code works for inserting an array from a form, but it inserts each value into it's own row. How can I insert an array into one row?

```
<?php 
require_once('config.php'); 
require_once('open_db.php');
$palette=$_POST['colors_palette'];
while (list ($key,$val) = @each ($palette)) {
}
For ($i=0; $i<sizeof($palette);$i++) {
$query="INSERT INTO style_test1 (colors_palette) VALUES ('".$palette[$i]."')";
Mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
Echo "Record is inserted";
?>

<form method="post" action="insert_array.php" >
<input type="checkbox" name="colors_palette[]" value="jewel" />                
<input type="checkbox" name="colors_palette[]" value="bright" />                     
<input type="checkbox" name="colors_palette[]" value="soft" /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="colors_palette[]" value="earth" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To insert as a **string**:

```
<?php 
 require_once('config.php'); 
 require_once('open_db.php');

 $palette=$_POST['colors_palette'];

 $query="INSERT INTO style_test1 (colors_palette) VALUES ('". serialize($palette) ."')";
 mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

 echo "Record is inserted";
?>
```

You could then `unserialize` to the get the data back as an array or object.

A better way to do it though, is to insert is as a **JSON formatted** string.

```
$query="INSERT INTO style_test1 (colors_palette) VALUES ('". json_encode($palette). "')";
```

Then you can use `json_decode` to decode it back to an array.

**Implode:**

```
$pal   = implode(',', $palette);
$query = "INSERT INTO style_test1 (colors_palette) VALUES ('".$pal."')";
```

Comment: There's no use to denormalize the data like that. On top of that, the question is "how it inserts each value into it's own row".

Comment: The asker already knows how to insert each into its own row. They want to insert the whole array into one row.

Comment: @Patrick That worked :-D It's showing up with unexpected formatting though - json_encode resulted in ["neutral","jewel","bright"]. What can I do to prevent the quotes and [] from being added to the database?

Comment: See **implode** in my updated answer. If it solved your problem, make sure to mark is as *best answer*.

Answer (score 1):

to convert array into comma separated variables use `implode` function in PHP as:

```
$query="INSERT INTO style_test1 (colors_palette) VALUES ('".implode(',',$palette)."')";
```

EDIT: try this code:

```
<?php 
 require_once('config.php'); 
 require_once('open_db.php');

 $palette=$_POST['colors_palette'];

 $query="INSERT INTO style_test1 (colors_palette) VALUES ('".implode(',',$palette)."')";
 mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

 echo "Record is inserted";
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Nothing was inserted and it gave me the error message: Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in...

Comment: Did you mean that I should retype the single quotes? If so, when I tried that there was a slight change - it inserted an empty line and I got 3 error messages:  "Undefined variable: i", "Undefined index" and "implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed"

Comment: if have single dim array so you can try it as implode(',',$palette) and remove the loop.

Comment: Thank you :-) Patrick and @João Mosmann just showed me how to do that :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP function

```
serialize($myArray);
```

This function transform a array into a string. So you can insert in a row field.

And use unserialize on the string to get a array.

You can too implode the array to get a string

```
$string = implode(',',$myArray);
```

Comment: explode is used to create an array out of a string and not the other way around

Comment: @João Mosmann That worked :-D And it'll be very helpful because some of my code requires a string :-)